# Using a variable in another method in another class -- how?

Tags: c#

I have two classes, `Class1` and `Class2`, `Class1` has a method named `Method1` with a variable named `variable1`. I'm wondering how I can call `variable1` from `Class2`-- I have down so far:

```
private Class1 instance = New Class1();
var variable2 = instance.Method1.variable1;
```

Inside of `Class2` However `variable2` is still not set to `variable1` --what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Show at least your `Method1` from the first class. You're not giving us anything to guide you with.

Comment: It depends what you are doing with `variable1` and where you are setting the value of either. If you set `variable2 = variable1` before `variable1` even equals anything, you'll end up with an empty `variable2`. As @krillgar has  said, you'll need to show the rest of your code so we can see what's happening (or isn't as the case may be).

Comment: You can if Class2 inherits Class1.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, you can't. Method-local variables only exist during the execution of the method. They can't be accessed outside of the method at all.